# Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :instant: - kapt - kaptDebug - kaptRelease

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps, kapt

I have app with instant module, instant module has only 2 dependencies base module and one feature module. I trying to generate signed apk but i have one problem:

```
Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :instant:
  - kapt
  - kaptDebug
  - kaptRelease
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration 'kapt':
      - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but no value provided.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' but no value provided.
  - Configuration 'kaptDebug':
      - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but no value provided.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' but no value provided.
  - Configuration 'kaptRelease':
      - Found artifactType 'processed-jar' but wasn't required.
      - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'release' but no value provided.
      - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Metadata' but no value provided.
```

I generate apk a lot of times, but today I have this error. When I trying to go to later commits they also has this problem, but one week ago this commits working fine.

This is my instant module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation project(':bo')
}
```

Here my feature module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation project(path: ':settings')
    implementation project(':video-player')

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'

    //RxJava
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'

    //time ago
    implementation 'com.github.marlonlom:timeago:3.0.2'
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but try removing the 2 `apply plugin` statements for `kotlin-android` and `kotlin-android-extensions` in the `instantapp` module.  This module doesn't contain any code, and these plugins probably don't expect to work with `instantapp` Gradle plugin.

Comment: Thanks! It's works. You really help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hassan Ibraheem says problem was in `apply plugin` statements for `kotlin-android` and `kotlin-android-extensions` in the instantapp module. I need just remove them because this module doesn't contain any code.